# Sql Server 2005 navarchar to IN

Tags: sql-server

I have a nvarchar value something like '1,3,5,6', in my database table

But I want to use this in a where condition, something like this 
where event_id IN (1,3,5,6)

How do I achieve that, 
How can I convert it and use in the IN of a query

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to achieve this. The good news is, there's no harm in this if you follow best practice and check for SQL injection. Good luck!

Comment: csv data in individual table cells in **evil**. fix your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be done via dynamic SQL.  Something like this.

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(20), @sql nvarchar(100)

set @val = (select SomeColumn from SomeTable)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE Column3 IN (' + @val + ')'

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for the details but, I need to use a little complicated query in the SET @sql section and it is not allowing me to execute 
It is giving the following error -'The multi-part identifier "a.aa" could not be bound.' and so on for each column in the select statement, please advice

Comment: Excellent. Don't forget to mark answers as correct on here as it'll help your reputation on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fig-out and fix it 
not sure why but the issue is

The query is not executing if I write

SET @sql =

but its working when I change to

EXEC ('SELECT TOP 20 a.aa, a.bb, a.cc, a.dd, c.pp, a.ee FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.ff= b.ff LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON a.gg= c.gg WHERE len(a.aa) > 0 AND b.aa IN ('+@val +') AND a.xx= 1')

Thank you